# Python - two separate conditions depending on value of independent column (USA / Canada zip code exercise)

Tags: python, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a new column in my data set that is dependent on two separate columns in my data (country and zip code).  If the country is "USA", I want the new column to take the data in the zip code column and remove everything after the "-" (leaving only the first five numbers).  If the country is "Canada" I want the new column to take the data in the zip code column, remove all spaces and input the data into the new column.  See example below.

[image]

I have tried several different things including the following but none of them have worked

(1) df['new column'] = [df['Zip Code'].str[:5] if x == 'USA' else 'no' for x in df['Country']]

(2) usa = df['Country'].str.contains('USA')

```
canada = df['Country'].str.contains('Canada')

df['PYZipCleaned'] = np.where(USA, 'USA', zipclean.str.replace('-',""))
```

Please help

Comment: “but none of them have worked” Can you elaborate? That’s quite vague.

Comment: I'm unable to execute both conditions.  I have been able to split out the first 5 numbers from the US zip code as I intended but the Canada ends up with all blank results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try acutally is pretty close - provided there's only the two countries, you can use an if else to treat the zip codes accordingly. Pythons `zip()`-function even allows you to throw everything into one list comprehension, though that doesn't necessarily make for the most readable code

```
df['new column'] = [el[0][:5] if el[1] == 'USA' else el[0].replace(' ', '') for el in zip(df['Zip Code'], df['Country'])]
```

What's going on is not too complicated: you checke if the country code is USA and if yes, just take the first 5 characters, else remove the whitespace by calling `string.replace`

For a way pretty close to what you proposed, use this:

```
df['new column'] = df['Zip Code'].str.replace(' ', '')
usa = df['Country'].str.contains('USA')
df['new column'][usa] = df['new column'][usa].str.slice(0,5)
```

The first line copies the zip code to the new column and takes care of the Canada formatting in one go. Since the USA rows don't contain spaces, this will only affect Canada rows. Then, you simply find the USA rows and slice them to your will.

**EDIT**:
As there is a few Canada samples with dash instead of whitespace, the following code block is the way to go

```
df['new column'] = df['Zip Code'].str.replace(' ', '').str.replace('-', '')
usa = df['Country'].str.contains('USA')
df['new column'][usa] = df['new column'][usa].str.slice(0,5)
```

Comment: What exactly is the first part of this code accomplishing?  
"el[0][:5] if el[1] == 'USA"
How does the code know which column to check for 'USA' in?

Comment: el is an element returned by the zip-Generator. It builds tuples where the first element is the Zip code and the second element is the country name: `zip(df['Zip Code'], df['Country'])`

Comment: ok I get it.  What if instead of editing a column with zip codes i was editing text based on country.  Would my first approach still be close?  I guess what I'm asking is how could I accomplish my objective without using the zip-Generator

Comment: Why would you not want to use `zip`? It's one of Pythons nicest features imo. Anyway, I'll think up a solution without zip, edit it into my original post and notify you via a comment

Comment: zip seems useful. But i'm doing a lot of data cleaning that is similar to this problem and seeing if there's anything else i can use

Comment: zip-less method is in. Turned out neater than I was expecting, and is pure pandas.Series.str manipulation, so it should be rather fast as well

Comment: There is one more issue.  Some of the Canadian zip codes contain a dash as well (ie V3G-J5K).  In order to remove these I wrote another line as follows:
df['new column'] = df['new column'].str.replace('-','')
Although this works as well, how would I include this condition in the original line of code?

Comment: Just chain another `.replace()` to the relevant element as in `el[0].replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')`

Comment: It's probably best not to use a list comprehension for this when it can easily be done using Pandas methods. Also, I believe that indexing like `df['new column'][usa]` can be replaced with `.loc[]`.

Comment: I've actually never done the timing, but pandas methods are likely faster, I agree.

Comment: I was more concerned with being idiomatic and clear, but you're right, I hadn't thought of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution to the one by Lukas Thaler, with a few tweaks. Notice the simple regex, to avoid multiple `replace` operations.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(['USA', 'CANADA', 'CANADA'], ['90210-5555', 'V5J 3L5', 'A1A-1A1']), columns=['Country', 'Zip'])

usa_mask = df_1['Country'] == 'USA'
canada_mask = df_1['Country'] == 'CANADA'

df_1.loc[usa_mask, 'New Col'] = df_1.loc[usa_mask, 'Zip'].str.slice(stop=5)
df_1.loc[canada_mask, 'New Col'] = df_1.loc[canada_mask, 'Zip'].str.replace(' |-', '')
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: what does "df_1.loc" actually do?

Comment: @wolfblitza `loc` is the standard method for indexing with labels or boolean arrays. First argument is row selector, second argument is column selector. You can find the documentation with all the details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html/).